# Why is a transposed matrix imaginary?

Tags: matrices

I have a postulate that states

$$ z^{*T} = -z $$
$$\begin{pmatrix} z_{11}^* &z_{12}^* \\
z_{21}^* & z_{22}^*
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} -z_{11} & -z_{12} \\
-z_{21} & -z_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$$

If this is true, the conlcusion was, that $z_{11}$ and $z_{22}$ would bouth be imaginary and if $z_{12} = z_{21}$ every matrix element would be imaginary. But there is no proof, so I wanted to ask why is that true?

Comment: Check it for $1\times 1$-matrices. Then $z=a+bi$, so that $a-bi=-(a+bi)$, hence $a=0$, as you said. So this can't be true. Just take $a=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_{11}=x_{11}+iy_{11}$

$$z_{11}^*=-z_{11} \iff
x_{11}-iy_{11}=-x_{11}-iy_{11} \iff
x_{11}=-x_{11} \iff x_{11}=0
$$

do the same for $z_{22}$